# Amazon S3 - How to automatically make the new content of a folder public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, directory, amazon-cloudfront, public

I'm using amazon s3 to store images in a bucket, and cloudfront to get and post those pictures. My problem is that every time I upload a new image, it's automatically private (trying to get it results in a 403 forbidden). To be able to get it and show it on my website, I have to make my folder public again (after I've already done it). Do you have any idea why is there this behaviour ?

My bucket is public and here are my IAM permissions:

```
// First strategy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:HeadBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:HeadObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
    }
  ]
}

// Second strategy
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "acm:ListCertificates",
        "cloudfront:*",
        "iam:ListServerCertificates",
        "waf:ListWebACLs",
        "waf:GetWebACL",
        "wafv2:ListWebACLs",
        "wafv2:GetWebACL"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

"my-bucket-name" is obviously replaced by the actual name of the bucket.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

If you wish to make objects publicly accessible (to people without IAM credentials), you have two options:

**Option 1: Bucket Policy**

You can create a **Bucket Policy** that makes content publicly accessible. For example, this policy grants `GetObject` access to *anyone*:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

You will also need to **turn off Block Public Access** on the S3 bucket to permit a Bucket policy.

**Option 2: Make the object public**

You could alternatively make specific objects in Amazon S3 public.

When uploading an object, specify an Access Control List (`ACL`) of `public-read`. You will also need to **turn off Block Public Access** to permit the object-level permissions.

When you say *"I have to make my folder public again"*, I suspect that you are going into the Amazon S3 console, selecting a folder and then using the **Make public** option. This is the equivalent of setting the `ACL`. You can avoid this extra step by specifying the ACL *while uploading the object* or using the Bucket Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Lambda trigger based on the prefix of your subfolder. Then during the create event update the permissions of the object to make it public.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html